# Where to get Kotlin Psi dependent library?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-plugin

I am looking into writing some IntelliJ plugin for Kotlin.

I see that there `org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.*` from the code
https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/idea/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/idea/inspections/LeakingThisInspection.kt

But I don't know what dependent to add (to my build.gradle) to access the Kotlin `psi`?

Answer (score 1):

I use the below dependent, and it works.

```
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

Where `$kotlin_version` is `1.2.50`