# Why is the kotlin-gradle-plugin failing to create a PSIFile from CodeInsightTestFixture.configureByText?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I created an IntelliJ plugin using the template https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-platform-plugin-template. The template comes with a test that runs on an XML file. I want to create a similar test for a Kotlin file. Here's the template test file plus my added test (`test2`):

```
package org.jetbrains.plugins.template

import com.intellij.ide.highlighter.XmlFileType
import com.intellij.psi.xml.XmlFile
import com.intellij.testFramework.TestDataPath
import com.intellij.testFramework.fixtures.BasePlatformTestCase
import com.intellij.util.PsiErrorElementUtil

@TestDataPath("\$CONTENT_ROOT/src/test/testData")
class MyPluginTest : BasePlatformTestCase() {

    fun testXMLFile() {
        val psiFile = myFixture.configureByText(XmlFileType.INSTANCE, "<foo>bar</foo>")
        val xmlFile = assertInstanceOf(psiFile, XmlFile::class.java)

        assertFalse(PsiErrorElementUtil.hasErrors(project, xmlFile.virtualFile))

        assertNotNull(xmlFile.rootTag)

        xmlFile.rootTag?.let {
            assertEquals("foo", it.name)
            assertEquals("bar", it.value.text)
        }
    }

    override fun getTestDataPath() = "src/test/testData/rename"

    fun testRename() {
        myFixture.testRename("foo.xml", "foo_after.xml", "a2")
    }
    
    // Here's my test
    fun test2() {
        val fileText: String = """
package com.loganmay.test

data class MyClass(val myString: String)
        """.trimIndent()
        val psiFile = myFixture.configureByText("a.kt", fileText)
        val xmlFile = assertInstanceOf(psiFile, XmlFile::class.java)
    }

}
```

Without changing the build.gradle file, that test fails with:

```
Expected instance of: com.intellij.psi.xml.XmlFile actual: com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiPlainTextFileImpl
```

I want it to parse the text as a `PsiFile` that's also a `KtFile`. From various sources, I've been led to believe that the fixture is parsing it as a plain text file because the test project doesn't have access to the Kotlin compiler. So, I added:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10")
}
```

to the build.gradle. Then, when I run the test, `configureByText` throws an exception with a big trace, the root exception of which is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: 'filetype.archive.display.name' is not found in java.util.PropertyResourceBundle@4ecbb519(messages.CoreBundle)
    ... 53 more
org.jetbrains.plugins.template.MyPluginTest > test2 FAILED
    com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException at ComponentManagerImpl.kt:511
        Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException at Registry.java:164
```

Does anyone have any insight into what the issue is or know how to resolve it?

Notes:

- I also tried importing the kotlin compiler and casting `psiFile as KtFile`, which produced the same error, an idea I got from [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009691499-Does-UAST-support-Kotlin-)
- [This project](https://github.com/Netflix/dgs-intellij-plugin/blob/main/src/test/kotlin/com/netflix/dgs/plugin/DgsInputArgumentInspectorTest.kt) has a test like this that may be working
- [This post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002951379-Testing-against-Kotlin-at-LightCodeInsightFixtureTestCase) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52125299/) recommend adding the kotlin gradle plugin, which I did
- [This question](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206147199-How-to-unit-test-PSI-related-code) seems similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yann Cebron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/723934/yann-c%C3%A9bron) replied on the [jetbrains help forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010813819-Get-all-PSI-Virtual-Files-within-a-project-?page=1#community_comment_7720573869202) with an answer for Java, which also worked for Kotlin.

The solution is to add a dependency to the IntelliJ gradle plugin. The template comes with these lines in the build.gradle:

```
intellij {
    pluginName.set(properties("pluginName"))
    version.set(properties("platformVersion"))
    type.set(properties("platformType"))

    // Plugin Dependencies. Uses `platformPlugins` property from the gradle.properties file.
    plugins.set(properties("platformPlugins").split(',').map(String::trim).filter(String::isNotEmpty))
}
```

So, didn't need to do anything there. In my gradle.properties, I added

```
platformPlugins = com.intellij.java, org.jetbrains.kotlin
```

To my plugin.xml, I added:

```
    <depends>com.intellij.modules.java</depends>
    <depends>org.jetbrains.kotlin</depends>
```

I was able to remove

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10")
}
```

from the build.gradle which I mentioned above.

Now, the test works for Java and Kotlin files.